# What does Is Staged mean in Informatica Connection object definition?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am trying to replicate an Informatica Powercenter mapping in Informatica Cloud. When looking at the Target table properties, found the attribute "Is Staged" in the target connection object definition.

The property Truncate Target Table can be inferred easily, it means Truncate table before it is being loaded with data. What does the property "Is Staged" mean?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`is Staged` the name says infa will stage the data into a staging area flat file. And then read from the file and load into target table. If its unchecked, data will be loaded using a direct targte writing pipeline.

This is done to make sure data is extracted from source asap and if there is a failure in load, you can restart and re-load.

But this is set for certain data sources. Also you need to setup stage directory.